# Check if my app has permissions to read process info and read/write to files and directories

Tags: c#, .net, process, permissions

How to check in my C# application if I have Permissions to get process list, kill processes, get directories, get files in directories, read and write files and etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If your has permission can do the operation without issue, if there is a lack of permission you can catch the exception and handle it(`UnauthorizedAccessException` etc).

Comment: Yep. "Try and see" is usually effective.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET there are two ways to do this.

The [System.Security.Permissions namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24ed02w7.aspx) has attributes and classes you need. You can use the attributes and write declarative code, or use the classes with imperative code.

As an example, for FileIO you would do this

**[Declarative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionattribute.aspx)** :
Typically you annotate a method, and based on the [SecurityAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityaction.aspx) exceptions are thrown is the current or calling code doesn't have the said permission

```
[FileIOPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.PermitOnly, 
           ViewAndModify = "C:\\example\\sample.txt")]
```

**[Imperative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx)**: Here you can programatically check for permissions

```
FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
try
{
  f.Demand();
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
}
```

Imperative or declarative, your code has to react to an exception. The [SecurityAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityaction.aspx) enum explains how these work, some check if the current code has permission, some check the calling code too. This enum has the same corresponding methods (Deny,Assert,etc) which can be used in imperative code.

Lastly, the [System.Security.Permissions namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24ed02w7.aspx) doesn't have anything for processes, so I assume you can't really check for permissions here.  Although it's for .NET 1.1 [this security article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288469%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is pretty relevant. (Doesn't have coloured code though =(